# Define and call a method using a formula

Tags: java

I'm trying to calculate the average gpa but I get an error.

```
public static double calculateAVG(int grade, int credit) {
double AVG;
if (education == grade) {
        AVG= (grades * credits) / credits;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Default");
}
return input.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You couldn't declare types on a function call. Change:

```
BFP = calculateBFP(int gender, int age, double BMI);
```

To

```
BFP = calculateBFP(gender, age, BMI);
```

Also, probably you could return not `input.nextDouble()` but `BFP` variable.

Answer (score 0):

1. your entire code should be in a  `public class`.
2. you would also need to `import java.util.Scanner` to use inputs from
   the user.

   3. your input.nextdouble() would take the input from you and return it, rather than your BFP which you have calculated. so `return BFP`